# Finding the Tolerance of Adaptive Quadrature Estimations

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

So I'm learning about the Adaptive Quadrature "Algorithm" for estimating numerical integration and I am have trouble figuring out how you can approximate the error and actual value between two nodes.  For clarification, the example at [this](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture30.pdf) link has an example problem where $|I_2 - I(f)|$ is approximately $(1/15) |I_2 - I_1|$.  I am having trouble seeing where they got that from.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank!

Answer (score 0):

The general method behind this is called Richardson extrapolation.

The error is of size $O(h^4)$, where $h$ is the length of the $n=1/h$ sub-intervals.. Extracting the dominating term, this means that the error has the form 
$$I(h)-I(0)=C·h^4+O(h^5).$$
Now we compare $I(h)$ and 
$$I(h/2)=I(0)+C·h^4/16+O(h^5)$$ 
Eliminating the leading error term this leads to
$$
16·I(h/2)-I(h)=16·I(0)-I(0)+O(h^5)
$$
and thus
$$
I(0)=\frac{16·I(h/2)-I(h)}{15}+O(h^5)
$$
so that
$$
I(h/2)-I(0)=\frac{I(h)-I(h/2)}{15}+O(h^5)
$$

In your source, $I_1=I(h)$, $I_2=I(h/2)$ and $I(f)=I(0)$.